# How can I open vim in a seperate window instead of in the terminal?

Tags: vim, text, editing

I installed vim via homebrew and have been using it in the terminal. However, it would be a lot more convenient for me if I could use vim like a GUI application (that means, text editing in another window and not inside the terminal window)

How can I achieve that? I know that there is a GUI version of vim but since I installed it via homebrew it wouldn't be a good idea to install the that one as well.

Is it possible to create some kind of alias that starts the vim gui version?

Comment: what happens when you run "vim -g"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [MacVim](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/), either with homebrew (with [this formula](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/macvim.rb)) or simply [by downloading an official build.](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/downloads/list)

Comment: is it true that home-brew will mess up if I also download the official build??

Comment: Honestly? I have no idea. The MacVim formula uses the official MacVim snapshot so you would end up with the same features as if you downloaded it but it also allows you to override the default Vim (in dirty ways, IMO) so, theoretically, Homebrew's MacVim will be be more "integrated" than "downloaded" MacVim. That said, I don't use Homebrew (MacPorts serves me well, thanks) and I run a "downloaded" MacVim.